# If-Else statement for a checkbox

Tags: c#, checkbox

I've got the following problem:
When my program checks for a determined condition and if the checkbox was checked, it throws the `MessageBox` twice; according to the debugger, it goes inside the if, throws the `messagebox` and then issue the `Checkbox1.Checked ==  false` . After that it executes the entire if condition again.
I've tried `MSDN` documentation about `Checkbox1.Threestate` but I couldn't get to implement it. What can I do to solve this checkbox issue ?

```
   private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string currPath = textBox1.Text;
        if (!textBox1.Text.Contains("\\"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please define the input folder before starting");
            checkBox1.Checked = false;                
        }
        else if (!textBox2.Text.Contains("\\"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please define the XML Output folder before starting");
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
        }
        else if (!textBox3.Text.Contains("\\"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please define the Converted PPF Output Folder before starting");
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
        }
        else if (!textBox4.Text.Contains("\\"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please define the Invalid PPF Output Folder before starting");
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // calls the watcher
            prg.ProgramProcessing(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, yes, you change the `checked` status of the checkbox so it will trigger the event again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you change the check inside the checkchange event, it trigger it a second time, you should unsubscribe the event, then resubscribe

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox1.CheckedChanged -= checkBox1_CheckedChanged;

    try
    {
        // Your conditions
    }
    finally
    {
        checkBox1.CheckedChanged += checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sucessfully implemented. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Thomas: I suggest (in general case) adding `try..finally`, i.e. `checkBox1.CheckedChanged -= checkBox1_CheckedChanged; try {...} finally {checkBox1.CheckedChanged += checkBox1_CheckedChanged;}` in case *your code* part has `return` or throws an exception

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you set `Checked = false`, you change its value, and the `Changed` event is fired again.

One way to solve this, is using a guard variable that makes sure you don't go through the code again while you are handling the event:

```
private bool handlingCheckboxChanged;
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(handlingCheckboxChanged) { return; }
  handlingCheckboxChanged = true;
  try {
    // Your original code
  } finally {
    handlingCheckboxChanged = false;
  }
}
```

Even better would be to make sure that the user cannot check the checkbox in the first place, for example by handling the change events of the text boxes and only enabling your checkbox once all the conditions have been met.

Comment: Your idea sounds good. But i would like the user to click and see the warning message for defining the folder before continues. If i just disable the checkbox he won't be able to "try to click".

Answer (score 1):

You could skip it if checkbox is not checked.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!checkBox1.Checked) return; //<- this.

    string currPath = textBox1.Text;
    if (!textBox1.Text.Contains("\\"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please define the input folder before starting");
        checkBox1.Checked = false;                
    }
    else if (!textBox2.Text.Contains("\\"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please define the XML Output folder before starting");
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
    }
    else if (!textBox3.Text.Contains("\\"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please define the Converted PPF Output Folder before starting");
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
    }
    else if (!textBox4.Text.Contains("\\"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please define the Invalid PPF Output Folder before starting");
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // calls the watcher
        prg.ProgramProcessing(textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple solution:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox1.CheckedChanged -= checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
    // Yours conditions
    checkBox1.CheckedChanged += checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
}
```

OR

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checkBox1.Checked == false)
    {
        return;
    }
    // your conditions..
}
```